# Nested RecyclerViews or RecyclerView inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Lets say that I want to have a horizontal list which itself contains several - variable number - vertical lists of certain views (couple of text views and buttons, nothing complicated).

Would it be more efficient to implement this as a RecyclerView(horizontal) with nested RecyclerViews(vertical), or a horizontal ScrollView and to somehow "append" my vertical RecyclerViews?

Comment: Neither, it is not recommended to have nested views when both are dynamically scrollable. Android doesn't handle this well. It has a hard time determining where/what you are exactly trying to scroll, and since the adapters have to manage the views that are actually being displayed it usually ends up just being a headache. Not that it can't be done, just not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a ViewPager (a horizontally swipeable container) that contains a vertical RecyclerView in each of the Pages.

If you are using AndroidStudio, there is a Code template (in the "New" menu) that will allow you to quickly create the ViewPager to get you started.

Comment: I know about ViewPagers, but in that case all my RecyclerViews would be in separate fragments, which means that I couldn't do stuff like drag and drop between them (move one item from one RV to another).

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure you can drag and drop easily between different RV in different Fragments anyway (but that is probably a different SO ? ).

Comment: Well no, that's my point. If I were using ViewPager with fragments then I COULDN'T d'n'd it between different fragments. If all RVs were in the same View, then I could do it.

Comment: I understand.  I think what you are trying to accomplish with a single RV is going to be super complicated.  The nature of RV is that it allows complicated structures, but this sounds like it is going to be super hard to accomplish with a single container.

Comment: @MarkoStojanovic if your goal is to drag/drop I would recommend using a single RecyclerView with an adapter that manages headers and different view types.